# Not able to launch electron app with arguments using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, .net, electron, ui-automation

I am trying to launch my electron app where it should accept my 'path to the index.js' and '--start server' as the arguments to load the html content of electron. But my chrome options not considering the arguments passed and it just opens the default electron.exe.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27OXM.png)

Below is the code I tried to launch app:

```cs
ChromeOptions electronOption = new ChromeOptions();  
electronOption.AddArguments("C:\Program Files\src\index.js", "--startServer");  
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("path to chromedriver.exe", "path to electron.exe");  
driver = new ChromeDriver(service, electronOption);
```